# How to display only date 2/2/2016 in infopath form?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath, infopath-rules

I have a date picker which will be calculated based on the below formula:

addDays(ColumnName, 15) when i submit the form in list is shows as
 2/2/2016 12:00:00 AM with time, I need only 2/2/2016 .

I tried using:

```
concat(number(substring(now(), 6, 2)), "/", number(substring(now(), 9, 2)), "/", number(substring(now(), 1, 4)))
```

but not worked. Can anyone help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a date picker simply go to the Date picker properties (right click on the field). In the **Data tab** - Add *now()* in the Default value. In the **Data Type** hit the '*Format*' button and choose the radio button '*Display the date like this*'. Below that are the options for how you would like the date formmated.

Not sure why you need the Concat formula to achieve the same results?

Comment: At first by clicking Format button we have kept Date and Time and now my clients asks only date, but in my case data are already there and so Format button is not enabled. So what I have to do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In the formula you have used, addDays (column, 15), SO I assume you are having a date field, where you wish to add 15 days and show the resulting date in a datepicker control in mm/dd/yyyy format. And since the 'column' you are referring to is a date time control you are also getting time when you add days to it.
You can try this
in the date picker control, use this formula: **addDays(substring-before(column, "T"), 15)**